# What is the meaning of "You are timing me"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

It was actually written as: "You timing me", which is grammatically incorrect, so I fixed that.

The question is: what that could possibly mean?

I have searched on the internet, but found nothing except "big time" and "timing".

Comment: The question would be clearer and easier to answer if you tell us where you found that sentence and give us more context.

Comment: @EddieKal But you have clarified it excellently.

Comment: **You timing me?** is a truncated form of "*Are* you timing me?"  The verb-to-be is often dropped in casual conversation in such questions.  *You having coffee or tea?*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo The question mark is not included in the sentence. It is for **my** question in the title. The origin one doesn't have any punctuation mark after it.

Comment: The phrase "You timing me" as a standalone clause would never be declarative; it would always be an interrogative with `BE` omitted.  That there was no question mark in the original is of no consequence when determining the meaning syntactically.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You are right. It all makes sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time can be a verb, meaning to "measure the duration of an activity done by someone".

When you say "time someone", it means the activity undertaken by that person is being measured, not the person that undertakes it.

[Merriam Webster's explanation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time):

> to determine or record the time, duration, or rate of
>
> *time a horse*